# How to setup parameters in a Backbone.Model to handle .fetch() function?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a question regarding the fetch function of Backbone. 
I've read from the Backbone documentation that it "Refreshes the model's state from the server." but on the server I don't have the same model, moreover how do I give the url connection with the server?
Is it like:

```
var model = new Backbone.Model({
some: "data",
});

model.url = "www.some.url";

setInterval(function(){
model.fetch();
}, 10000);
```

And this would fetch from some.url every 10 seconds some JSON I guess, right? Where exactly do I receive & process this JSON?

Thanks a lot

Masiar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out by myself a simple solution:

```
setInterval(function(){
    model.fetch({
        success: function(){
            //do something
        }
    });
 }, 10000);
```

Hope this is going to be helpful for someone else!

Cheers,
Masiar